# How to show image in color channel of a image not in grayscale?

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.6

I was trying to obtain a image in colour channel but not in grayscale. Here is the code for it :-

```
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
blue = img[:,:,0].copy() # Blue channel image
blue[:,:,1] = 0  # Making green channel 0
blue[:,:,2] = 0  # Making red channel 0
```

But, when I try to make green channel and red channel 0 of the blue channel of the "image.jpg", it gives an error pointing to line 3 and line 4.

Error: `IndexError: too many indices for array`

I am using OpenCV 3.3 and python 3.6 on mac.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `blue = img.copy()`?

Comment: `blue = img.copy()` will create a copy of just `img`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Then you still need the next two lines

Comment: So you copy 1 channel and then try to access the other 2 non-existent channels

Comment: You have a 3 dimensional array (`img`). Copy the first channel of that array into other variable `blue` which is  a *2* dimensional array. And then you try to access third index of a two dimensional array. `too many indices for array`, the error is pretty clear.

Comment: I got your point api55 and Jose A. Then, why the image is in grayscale by `blue=img[:,:,0]` not in blue colour ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here you go:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_channel(im, n):
    if 0 <= n <= 2 and im.shape[2]==3:
        new_im = np.zeros_like(im)
        new_im[:, :, n] = im[:, :, n]

        return new_im
    return False

im = cv2.imread(your_image_filename_goes_here)
cv2.imshow("Chanel", get_channel(im, 0))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thing is in your example `blue` has shape (x, y) while `img` has shape (x, y, 3). That's why showing blue is grayscale, because being a two dimensional array opencv does not know that it is a blue channel.

A color image is just three "grayscale images" put together, although they don't represent light intensity as a plain grayscale image does, they represent certain color light intensity. And a combination of the three channels gives the color.

Grayscale image is just a two dimensional array of integers (3, 3):

```
y y y
y y y
y y y
```

While RGB (or in OpenCV BGR) image is a three dimensional array of integers (3, 3, 3):

```
B B B    G G G    R R R
B B B    G G G    R R R
B B B    G G G    R R R
```

If you just take the first channel of the BGR image, you are taking (3, 3):

```
B B B
B B B
B B B
```

And for OpenCV that is identical to a grayscale image.

Comment: Ok. Then how `blue` which has shape of (x,y) getting displayed ?

Comment: @AQ Because it is a grayscale image after all.

Comment: What's the difference between a 2-D grayscale(only blue) image and 3-D image with red and green channel 0 ?

Answer (score 3):

Do channels split, then merge with zeros:

```
img = cv2.imread("ColorChecker.png")
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
I0 = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
B = np.dstack([b,I0,I0])
G = np.dstack([I0,g,I0])
R = np.dstack([I0,I0,r])
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between a 2-D image obtained by `blue=img[:,:,0]` and 3-D image obtained by `img[:,:,1]=img[:,:,2]=0` for an image `img` ?

Comment: @AQ `blue=img[:,:,0]` means you just the blue channel, it's grayscale. `img[:,:,1]=img[:,:,2]=0 ` means you preserve the blue and set green and red to zeros, so it will show just in blue color. Remember, 2-D is grayscale, 3-D maybe in color (except B=G=R, still grayscale).